Trivial vs Non-Trivial Bandgap in Optics
Can someone please explain what is the meaning of trivial and non-trivial bandgap in the context of topological photonics? This term often comes in the papers with band structure images which I can't apprehend.

I am not familiar with topological photonics, but for topological insulators, the adjective "trivial" is usually used for any effects that are present in an ordinary insulator. Any "nontrivial" effects are caused by the topological property of the material.
